# Do not create pidfile and logfile when running celery worker as a daemon

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

While running the celery working using the following command creates two files `w1.log` and `w1.pid` which I do not want.

```
celery multi start w1 -A destiPak.celery -l info
```

Output

```
celery multi v3.1.20 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
        > w1@foo-bar: OK
```

### Show worker

```
 celery multi show w1
```

### Output

```
/Users/foo/bar/bin/python -m celery worker --detach -n w1@foo-bar --pidfile=w1.pid --logfile=w1.log --executable=/Users/foo/bar/bin/python
```

Suggestions, how to avoid creating those log file while `Running the worker as a daemon`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand why you would not want these files - the pid file is only a few bytes and the log files will contain useful information, and you can use `logrotate` or whatever to ensure that they do not take up too much space.

That said, if you use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage the workers instead of `celery multi` you can configure it to not generate log files, plus it does not use .pid files.

here's a `supervisord` config file that should do what you want

```
[program:celery]
command=celery worker -n w1@foo-bar
autostart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/null
redirect_stderr=true
```